# Android Tesseract OCR - How to get progress update during OCR process using the ProgressNotifier?

Tags: java, android, tesseract

I am completely new to android development and I'm trying to create an OCR app. Now my problem is I want to get the progress during the process of ocr.

And I found a blog post of rmtheis about this but I don't know how to implement it to my project.

Here is the code to his blog:

> The progress percentage can be used in a thermometer-style ProgressBar. The bounding boxes can be drawn on top of the display of the input image during recognition.
>
> Implementing this callback requires using an alternate constructor for the TessBaseAPI object and implementation of the ProgressNotifier interface:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

// Create the TessBaseAPI object, and register to receive OCR progress updates
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI(this);
baseApi.getHOCRText(myImage);

@Override
public void onProgressValues(ProgressValues progressValues) {
progressBar.setProgress(progressValues.getPercent());}
```

**Here is my code for in TessBaseOCR.java**

```
public class TessOCR{

private TessBaseAPI mTess;
public TessOCR(String language){
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
   // AssetManager assetManager=
    String datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ImageToText/";

   // AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    File dir = new File(datapath + "/tessdata/");
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

    mTess.init(datapath, language);

}

public String getOCRResult(Bitmap bitmap) {

    mTess.setImage(bitmap);
    String result = mTess.getUTF8Text();

    return result;

  //  TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    //baseApi.getUTF8Text();
 }
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mTess != null)
        mTess.stop();

}

}
```

**In my CropActivity.Java:**

```
public class CropActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
TessBaseAPI.ProgressNotifier{

 ProgressBar progressBar;

 @Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  //my codes here

 }

 //Some codes here


 //my Scan button
 public void onScanClick(View view) {

    try {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        //mImage.setImageBitmap(converted);

        doOCR(convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(bitmap) );

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Load an image first!", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
 public void ocrprogressbar() {
```

**I use layout inflater that will popup when scan button is pressed and from there I have my progressBar that I want get the progress update of Ocr**

```
     LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
     final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.ocr_progress, null);

     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
             context);

     progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

     TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtprcnt);


     // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
     alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

     alertDialogBuilder
             .setCancelable(false)
             .setPositiveButton("Stop",
                     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
      {
                        mTessOCR.onDestroy();
                         }
                     });



     // create alert dialog
     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

     // show it
     alertDialog.show();
     // set prompts.xml to alertdialog build

 }
public void doOCR(final Bitmap bitmap) {
   
   ocrprogressbar();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            final String result = mTessOCR.getOCRResult(bitmap).toString();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (result != null && !result.equals("")) {
                        String s = result.trim();

                        textView.setText(result);
                        finalresult = textView.getText().toString();
                            startActivityOnOCRresult();

                    }
                    //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        };

    }


    )
            .start();
}


 //My override method as what mentioned in the blog post

@Override
public void onProgressValues (TessBaseAPI.ProgressValues progressValues){
    progressBar.setProgress(progressValues.getPercent());


}


}
```

**My ocr_progress.xml layout that will be inflated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="Processing..."
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**My progressbar pops up but It's stucked and not getting progress. I am not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Please help me**